# How can I call hide() on an object on the screen using vue-konva?

Tags: vue.js, konvajs, vue-konva

What is the object that is containing the v-xxx item (v-circle for example)? I want to simply call hide() on that object, and thought may be ref plays a key roll, but that was not successful (got this.$refs.testCircle.show is not a function).

Following is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-visvesvaraya-ghbj0?file=/src/App.vue) I created to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the Core API section of https://github.com/konvajs/vue-konva

`$refs` was correct but had to call `getNode()` after the referenced node.

So in my example's case, I needed to call

```
this.$refs.testCircle.getNode().show()
```